# Formatting class instance return (list)

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm having difficulty with formatting when an instance that is a list is printed.
If I defined a class and created a class instance as the following:

```
class Building():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rooms = []

    def add_room(self, rm_num: str, occupied: str, type: str, size: str):
        self.rooms.append([rm_num, occupied, type, size])

>>>b = Building()
>>>b.add_room('302', 'Y', 'single', 'small')
>>>b.add_room('105', 'Y', 'single', 'large')
```

The goal right now is for the output when the instance is printed to look like the following:
(each item in the list instance on a separate line**)

```
>>>print(b)
302, Y, single, small
105, Y, single, large
```

How could I go about formatting through `def __repr__(self)`?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: do you know how to iterate through a list? how to format and print? What have you tried? Was there some specific problem you can into?

Comment: I was trying to iterate through a list up to 10 sublists in the list when printing. I figure I should just add some limitations to the add_room method to only add up to 10 at a time. But regarding formatting and printing for class instances specifically, I think I do need to review the basics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__repr__/) for repr. Also, look into [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) in python.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "\n".join(', '.join(x) for x in self.rooms)
```

Comment: you don't need the [] - since the comprehension is well delinieated

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved it right away. Like I commented in the initial question, I was trying to only print up to 10 sublists of the class instance list (which maybe I should have explained in the question) but I'll work around with the class method. The links are really helpful!